# Spring Boot: CORS working with GET request but not POST request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cors

Problem:

CORS is working with GET requests that do not have `@AuthenticatedPrincipal` in the method parameter.

I'm using

- OKTA as my authentication server.
- Spring REST controllers
- Spring Data (CrudRepository)

For some reason, I'm getting this error everytime, I am making a POST, PUT or unsafe request that has `@AuthenticatedPrincipal` in the method parameter, but it is working for GET requests:

[Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Iemt.png)

I have read every possible Stackoverflow question on CORS settings with Spring Boot and configured my CORS like this but to no avail:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
//                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
//                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers( "/courses", "/testing/*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .oauth2Login().and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }

//    @Bean
//    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
//        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
//        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
//        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("POST", "GET", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "HEAD", "DELETE"));
//        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Content-Type"));
//        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Link", "X-Total-Count", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers"));
//        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
//        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
//        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
//        return source;
//    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(ImmutableList.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(ImmutableList.of("OPTIONS", "HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        // setAllowCredentials(true) is important, otherwise:
        // The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the
        // request's credentials mode is 'include'.
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        // setAllowedHeaders is important! Without it, OPTIONS preflight request
        // will fail with 403 Invalid CORS request
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(ImmutableList.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

My Controllers

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping(EndPoints.TEST_PATH)
public class TestController {

    private final TestService tService;

    @Autowired
    public TestController(TestService tService) {
        this.tService = tService;
    }

    @PostMapping(path="/create")
    public ResponseEntity<String> addNewTest(@Valid @NonNull @RequestBody TestDTO data,
                                               @AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt principal){

        tokenUserEmail =  token.getClaimAsString("sub");
        tokenUid = token.getClaimAsString("uid");
        tokenFullName = token.getClaimAsString("firstName") + " "
                + token.getClaimAsString("lastName");
        
        TestEntity testEntity = new TestEntity();
        testEntity.setName(tokenFullName);
        testEntity.setGrade(data.grade);
        testEntity.setNumber(data.number);

        tService.addNewTest(testEntity);
        
    }
    

}
```

I have exhausted every single possible Stackoverflow question, created `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter()`, set and unset `@CrossOrigin`. At this point, I don't know what else can I do ... Anyone knows how do I fix this??

Comment: The image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Iemt.png shows that the issue is with a response from an Okta authentication endpoint — an OAuth endpoint. That endpoint is not CORS-enabled. No OAuth endpoints like that are ever CORS-enabled — very intentionally, because they’re no intended to be called from XHR/Fetch/Ajax in frontend JavaScript code running in a browser. Instead, users are meant to navigate to that endpoint and then get redirected back to your application.

Answer (score -1):

In CORS browser always send simple cross domain request like GET requests to the server. But browser check the response header(Access-Control-Allow-Origin) from the server whether cross domain request is allowed by the server. That's why your **GET** request is hitting the server. But non simple requests like **POST, PUT, DELETE** browser can't let the requests to hit the server. Instead browser sends preflight request to the server to check whether it allows cross domain request. If the response from the server contains the headers for support cross domain requests, only then browser will perform the actual request. This pre-flight request is send as **OPTIONS** request. That's why your error saying response to preflight request doesn't pass.
After we enable spring security all the preflight requests are blocked for non-authenticated users by spring security. To allow preflight request through we have to configure in the security configuration.

[image]

Remove disable() after the csrf().Then add the **@CrossOrigin** annotation at the top of the method. You can mention the domain inside the annotation as well. **@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:3000")**

This is the only thing you have to do.

Answer (score -1):

A **preflight** request is a small request that is sent by the browser before the actual request. It contains information like which HTTP method is used, as well as if any custom *HTTP headers* are present (like `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`).

When performing `POST` action, there are 2 steps. The first one is making an `OPTIONS` request, hence *preflight* request. Once the *preflight* is done, your browser knows what request types are allowed or denied.

In your case, the issue is that while your back-end expects 1 call, you are sending 2 *(preflight + actual request)*.

To solve this problem, you have to tell your back-end to respond **OK** when an `OPTIONS` request arrives and validate the others.

**DISCLAIMER:** I didn't try it with the way you configured *cors* (`CorsConfigurationSource` ). But, let me show it with a simple filter bean

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", ""Authorization, Cache-Control, Content-Type"");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        
        //SEND OK or validate
        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(((HttpServletRequest) req).getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        //
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer has been down-voted because on my side just adding the "OPTIONS" in the list of operations for "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" fixed my issue.